# Blue dot on cursor

Tags: monaco-editor

I implemented the monaco editor in an angular app that is using the VMWare clarify system.

But when initializing the editor I get the following cursor:

[image]

There's a blu dot on the cursor! Is this a monaco editor setting? Css?

Answer (score 3):

For me the blue dot was coming from Tailwind. I disabled it like this:

```css
.monaco-editor textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

I'm using Next.js so I put that in a file called `styles.css` and added `import 'styles.css'` to my `_app.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. Turned out that `monaco` adds an invisible focused `textarea` element at cursor position. And somewhere else I had styles to outline focused `textarea`s.

So the fix was making something like

```
.monaco{
  textarea{
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed the dot, but I'm using React. I noticed the CSS classes `inputarea monaco-mouse-cursor-text` target this dot. I wanted to hide the dot and the following worked:

```
.inputarea.monaco-mouse-cursor-text {
  opacity: 0;
}
```